# How to submit modal with ajax and send data to another modal YII2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I've got modal window and from it I call another modal. I want to close second modal and send $model to first modal (action)... I use this code http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/690/render-a-form-in-a-modal-popup-using-ajax/

View

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
 'id' => 'form-deposit',
 'action' => ' ',
 'options'=>[
    'onsubmit'=>'submitForm',
 ]
 ]);?>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'sum')->textInput() ?>
```

JS

```
function submitForm($form) {
    $.post(
        $form.attr("action"), // serialize Yii2 form
        $form.serialize()
    )
        .done(function(result) {
            //$form.parent().html(result.message);
            $('#modalreference-edit').modal('hide');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("server error");
            $form.replaceWith('<button class="newType">Fail</button>').fadeOut()
        });
    return false;
}
```

controller

```
public function actionCreatedeposit()
    {
        $model = new FinanceIncomeExpenses();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model->refresh();
        }     
        else {
            if(Yii::$app->getRequest()->isAjax){
                return $this->renderAjax('deposit/create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }else{
                return $this->render('deposit/create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

If i disable action it close both modal windows and nothing write in db.  When i use action i've got the blank page.